# Authentication in the Google Analytics API

Tags: authentication, google-analytics, oauth-2.0

We currently have an account with our company that we use to collect some information from the GA account of our customers.

This account is an @ourdomain account.

We intend to automate these queries by performing them via the GA API.

When creating an authentication key, an account is automatically created @ query-domain-domains.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

I ask, is it possible to create an authentication key (JSON) for the account that is already readable in our client accounts, or will we have to ask the more than 1000 domains to add permission to our new user?

Thank you for any help.

Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

To give permissions to a new user account you have to have permissions in the first place, so you cannot create a new service account that already has them.

However if your already have a user account with user management permissions you can use that to insert the service account programmatically via the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks).

Comment: Hello,

The current user has permissions, but I am not able to create an authentication json key.

The user who has the key, is not allowed.

I ask, is it possible to create a key for the user who is currently allowed?